# How do i git checkout multiple pr

Tags: git, github

I am new to github, there is a repo or library? that i am using, i would like to run some of the available PR that have not yet been merged into the branch i am running.

I fetched them all with

git fetch origin +refs/pull/*/merge:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*

then pulled
git checkout origin/pr/1282

this worked and the files changed in my folder, i then pulled another
git checkout origin/pr/1275

The files from the first pull reverted. How do i test/ run multiple pr?

i also tried but failed with
git checkout origin/pr/1293 origin/pr/1282 origin/pr/1287 origin/pr/1269

Thankyou

Comment: What do you mean by "test/run multiple pr?"  In Git, you typically have one working directory.  Do you want to combine changes from multiple pull requests and test all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have got it working by using 
git merge origin/pr/1293 origin/pr/1282 origin/pr/1287

Answer (score 2):

`git checkout` checks out a particular code version.  you said,

> then pulled git checkout origin/pr/1282

But you haven't *pulled*, you've *checked out*.

What you want to do is probably to check out a branch to work in,

```
git checkout -b my-merge-branch
```

Then pull in the PRs you want:

```
git pull origin origin/pr/1293 origin/pr/1282 origin/pr/1287
```

Creating a new code version with all the changes from those refs.

Comment: create and named a branch then tried git pull but it returns
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref pr/1293

Comment: did you have `origin` in there?

Comment: maybe it should be `refs/pr/1293` or `origin/pr/1293`, i'm not exactly sure

Comment: (.env) wings@wings:~/drytrade$ git checkout -b prbranchtest
Switched to a new branch 'prbranchtest'
(.env) wings@wings:~/drytrade$ git pull origin pr/1293 pr/1282 pr/1287 pr/1269 pr/1276
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref pr/1293

Comment: That's a separate issue anyway. The answer tells you how to pull down PRs which exist; trying to pull ones which don't is obviously not going to happen.

Comment: surely they exist as i can checkout?

Comment: did you try origin/pr/... ?

Comment: yes i tried git pull origin/pr/1282, didnt work, git checkout origin/pr/1282 works

Answer (score 0):

Another option if previous answer didn't work for you:

```
git remote add {the-repo} https://github.com/the/repo.git
git fetch --all && git checkout {the-repo}/{the-branch}

# Pull all PRs at once:
git pull --no-commit --squash -X theirs {the-repo} pull/3/head pull/5/head pull/7/head pull/9/head

# Or pull PRs one by one if all-at-one failed to merge:
git pull --rebase -X theirs {the-repo} pull/3/head
git pull --rebase -X theirs {the-repo} pull/5/head
git pull --rebase -X theirs {the-repo} pull/7/head
git pull --rebase -X theirs {the-repo} pull/9/head
```